# touch-screen (tablet PC) keeps de-registering making system unusable

Tags: tablet

I have a tablet PC (Yoga Book C930) with Wacom support which **worked fine for a few months.** A few weeks ago it became incredibly slow and often the window manager seems to restart or the desktop manager restarts entirely. (Windows is also installed and no problems there.)

In `dmesg` it seems that the USB HID device(s) are constantly being de-registered and re-registered. The problem is there is no *reason* given for being de-registered and it does not happen at predictable intervals. Occasionally it's fine for a minute but then starts doing it every few seconds.

Unfortunately I am not sure if it broke after an update.
However I know for sure that things worked in the past when I was using kernel 4.15.0-51 and a few later ones. Now I have gone back and tried that kernel (4.15.0-51) and several later ones through to 4.15.0-70, with no success.

I also just did an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 (kernel 5.3.0) and still nothing.

I get this kind of loop in dmesg:

```
[  173.554396] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[  173.917015] hid-generic 0003:048D:8951.008D: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1
[  173.929225] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.008E/input/input795
[  173.991177] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.008E/input/input796
[  173.991259] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Wireless Radio Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.008E/input/input797
[  173.991372] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.008E/input/input799
[  173.991503] hid-multitouch 0003:048D:8951.008E: input,hiddev1,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input2
[  174.019922] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.3/0003:048D:8951.008F/input/input800
[  174.020151] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.3/0003:048D:8951.008F/input/input803
[  174.021248] hid-multitouch 0003:048D:8951.008F: input,hiddev2,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input3
[  174.022442] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  174.022443] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[  174.044101] input: Wacom HID 5182 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-1/i2c-WCOM5182:00/0018:056A:5182.0002/input/input809
[  174.044977] input: Wacom HID 5182 Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-1/i2c-WCOM5182:00/0018:056A:5182.0002/input/input810
[  174.045326] wacom 0018:056A:5182.0002: hidraw3: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [WCOM5182:00 056A:5182] on i2c-WCOM5182:00
[  174.900663] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[  175.315543] hid-generic 0003:048D:8951.0090: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1
[  175.330506] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.0091/input/input812
[  175.391153] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.0091/input/input813
[  175.391338] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Wireless Radio Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.0091/input/input814
[  175.391482] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.0091/input/input816
[  175.391604] hid-multitouch 0003:048D:8951.0091: input,hiddev1,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input2
[  175.421713] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.3/0003:048D:8951.0092/input/input817
[  175.421999] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.3/0003:048D:8951.0092/input/input820
[  175.423156] hid-multitouch 0003:048D:8951.0092: input,hiddev2,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input3
[  175.423290] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  175.423291] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[  175.451410] input: Wacom HID 5182 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-1/i2c-WCOM5182:00/0018:056A:5182.0002/input/input826
[  175.451770] input: Wacom HID 5182 Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-1/i2c-WCOM5182:00/0018:056A:5182.0002/input/input827
[  175.452257] wacom 0018:056A:5182.0002: hidraw3: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [WCOM5182:00 056A:5182] on i2c-WCOM5182:00
[  178.469147] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[  178.870459] hid-generic 0003:048D:8951.0093: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1
[  178.885441] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.0094/input/input829
[  178.943631] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.0094/input/input830
[  178.943746] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Wireless Radio Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.0094/input/input831
[  178.943857] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.2/0003:048D:8951.0094/input/input833
[  178.944073] hid-multitouch 0003:048D:8951.0094: input,hiddev1,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input2
[  178.971708] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.3/0003:048D:8951.0095/input/input834
[  178.971921] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.3/0003:048D:8951.0095/input/input837
[  178.974611] hid-multitouch 0003:048D:8951.0095: input,hiddev2,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input3
[  178.975352] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  178.975354] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[  178.999887] input: Wacom HID 5182 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-1/i2c-WCOM5182:00/0018:056A:5182.0002/input/input843
[  179.000273] input: Wacom HID 5182 Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-1/i2c-WCOM5182:00/0018:056A:5182.0002/input/input844
[  179.000633] wacom 0018:056A:5182.0002: hidraw3: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [WCOM5182:00 056A:5182] on i2c-WCOM5182:00
[  184.761394] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[  185.165085] hid-generic 0003:048D:8951.0096: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE T-CON] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1
```

etc.

I'd like to highlight these lines:

```
[  173.554396] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[  174.022442] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  174.022443] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[  174.900663] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[  175.423290] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  175.423291] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[  178.469147] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[  178.975352] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  178.975354] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[  184.761394] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
```

Note that the "deregistering" entries come out of the blue a few seconds after the previous log entry. There is no error or anything.

If I blacklist `usbhid` (while the system is running) the problem is gone and when I un-blacklist it (while the system is running) it comes back.

Is there some other event log or something I can check?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 hasn't been released yet, being the development release or ubuntu+1 which is off-topic on this site.  It has other support options, however you'll have to wait until official release to use this site https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  (we can suggest filing a bug report on launchpad.net if you believe it's an issue because of later kernel thus a 20.04 related bug)

Comment: I have the same issue in 18.04...?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is on-topic for this site, however it doesn't use the 4.0 kernel you mention (*it was a test kernel in Ubuntu only in 2015 well before 18.04's release in 2018-April, Ubuntu 15.10 used 4.2, 16.04 used 4.4 etc so you're talking a very very old kernel*).  Ubuntu 18.04 has two supported kernel, neither of which is the 5.3 found in Ubuntu 20.04 (*my own system is 20.04 too as I use it myself, but I know not to mention it here if I need support as it's off-topic here; myself I use IRC for ubuntu+1*)

Comment: Chill! That was a typo. 4.15.0. Edited.

Comment: To make myself extra clear—I had this problem on a stock standard Ubuntu 18.04 with all the latest updates. Changing to earlier (known-good) or later kernel versions didn't help. Changing to a bleeding-edge distro didn't help either.